# Excel Formula to figure out number of bits required to finish the last octet of a subnet mask

Tags: microsoft-excel

My Business Applications professor gave us a question where we have an IP Address (`160.35.128.93`) and we have to use a formula to figure out what the required number of bits is required for the last octet of the IP Address and we have to make sure the number is rounded up. For example, his answer is that there are 6 required bits. The formula I'm using right now is `IMLOG2(number_of_subnets+2)` but after an hour of trying, I can't seem to get the right answer. Help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question you were given makes no sense. The subnet mask does not depend on the address to such precision; it could go all the way from e.g. /2 or /4 up to /30 or /31.

Comment: To make sure that I didn't mess it up, here's the question word for word:

Comment: 2. The formula to calculate the number of bits we require in the last octet for the subnet is Log2(number_of_subnets+2). Determine the function you need to use to find the number of bits we use to finish the subnet mask.

Comment: It is better to [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1403659/edit) instead of adding information in comments. You have the formula, where is the problem exactly?

Comment: Just use =LOG((num of subnets + 2),2).  I don't think you have a complex number your dealing with.

Comment: @SmartphoneUser: Right, that formula makes sense (except for the "+2" part, that's useless), but it has nothing to do with any specific IP address. Once you have the number of bits, I think you may be looking for `256-(2**numbits)` for the old-style netmask?